# How different are open and closed intervals?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I am taking an online maths course and I got little confused on the concepts of open and closed intervals. In the lecture, professor says there is a big difference between $(a, b)$ and $[a, b]$. The reason isn't very clear. To me it looks like they are very similar. The interval $(a, b)$ has two numbers fewer than $[a, b]$. In other words $(a, b)$ has all members of $[a, b]$ except $a$ and $b$. Clearly my reasoning must be false since professor has emphasized there is a big difference. Can anyone give the reason why there is a big difference?

[image]

Comment: Something called “compactness” is the most relevant one. If you can “cover” $[a,b]$ with a (possibly infinite) collection of open intervals, then you can actually select a finite number of them that suffice to cover. The same is not true of $(a,b)$, as witnessed by taking $(a+\frac{1}{n},b-\frac{1}{n})$ for all $n\geq \frac{2}{b-a}$.

Comment: To be honest in your context I think he was just trying to emphasize the fact they were different so you don't forget. A lot of theorem statements specifically require the interval to be closed/open, so you really should not interchange the two (so it is important). The contents of both sets are very similar, so in a sense there's not a lot of difference - but the difference is important. Although as @ArturoMagidin said - if you bring Topology in the game, there literally is a *big distinction* between ${(a,b)}$ and ${[a,b]}$.

Comment: The numbers that are missing are endpoints.  It turns out endpoints are a ***!!!HUGE!!!*** deal.  The difference is if a set has end points then you can approach the limits of the set and **!!!WHAM!!!** you *hit* it..  Right on the noggin!  If a set doesn't have end points you can approach the limits of the set.... and *never* get there.  From every point in the set you can *always* get closer and you never hit the limit.... Okay... so I hear you asking who cares and... well continue the study of mathematics and you will have a *lot* to entertain you.

Comment: The idea of an interval itself looks simple but it is not. For all kinds of intervals you may have seen in your textbook the following is a common feature : if two points lie in an interval then all the intermediate points also lie in that interval. Try proving the reverse that any set with this property must have end points (finite or infinite, included in set or not).

Comment: @fleablood thanks for the comment. this is more clear for me so far. so if i understand correctly there is a huge distinction between (1, 2) and [1, 2] because while you can hit 1 and 2 in closed interval you can never hit 2 and 1 in open interval. so in a way it seems there is a huge distance maybe infinity to approach 2 or 1 in open case but in closed interval you can finally hit it. so because of the difference in distance you can say they are very different? is this a correct way to see it? thanks!

Comment: That's a very informal way to look at it.  But that's the general idea.  One key purpose of mathematics is to come up with consistent formal ways to define such intuitive concepts.

Comment: @thank you. I am first trying to get intuitive understanding. I know there are formal proofs.

Answer (score 3):

There is a HUGE difference between closed and open intervals. To explain why, I will make a list of some properties of *continuous functions* on $[a,b]$ and on $(a,b)$ (by "function" I always mean real-valued functions).

1. *Every* continuous function $f(x)$ on $[a,b]$ is bounded: there are numbers $m$ and $M$ such that $m \leq f(x) \leq M$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$. This is false for some continuous functions on $(a,b)$, such as $1/(x-a)$, which leaks to $\infty$ on the left (vertical asymptote).
2. *Every* continuous function on $[a,b]$ is integrable (this assumes you have taken calculus, so you know what that means). This is not true for some continuous functions on $(a,b)$. That every continuous function on $[a,b]$ is integrable is closely related to every continuous function on $[a,b]$ satisfying a strong property called unform continuity, which is not satisfied by some continuous functions on $(a,b)$.
3. The image (set of all values) of *every* continuous function $f(x)$ on $[a,b]$ is also a closed interval $[c,d]$. This is not true of some continuous functions on $(a,b)$, such as $f(x) = (x-(a+b)/2)^2$, whose values are the half-open interval $[0,((a-b)/2)^2)$.

Mathematicians recognize all of these properties of the *continuous functions* on $[a,b]$ as being related to $[a,b]$ being what is called "compact". It is a subtle property to appreciate until you starting *proving theorems* about continuous functions. All the continuous functions on a compact set have a long list of attractive properties, which can fail for some continuous functions on a noncompact set. That $[a,b]$ is compact while $(a,b)$ is not is why $[a,b]$ and $(a,b)$ are regarded as enormously different from each other.

I once had a student in my office who said that the student's real analysis professor was going on and on about $[0,1]$ vs. $(0,1)$ and the student did not understand what the big deal was, since they seem to be practically the same sets except one contains its endpoints and the other doesn't. I laughed and said this seemingly minor distinction is in fact a HUGE distinction that accounts for the central role of closed bounded intervals in analysis. I do not know if the student ever came to appreciate this distinction.

It's not the case that open intervals are always terrible things. Indeed, continuous functions on all intervals (closed, open, half-open) have the nice property that their image is again an interval. In topology this is subsumed under the property that intervals are the "connected sets" in the real line. What makes $[a,b]$ better than $(a,b)$ is that $[a,b]$ is connected and compact, while $(a,b)$ is connected but not compact.

All the distinctions I have made above between $[a,b]$ and $(a,b)$ are related to the area of math called topology. In other areas of math the intervals $(a,b)$ and $[a,b]$ behave in very similar ways. For example, these two intervals have essentially the same properties as far as the subject called *measure theory* is concerned (I have in mind properties of Lebesgue measure on $[a,b]$ and $(a,b)$).  In measure theory there is no profound difference between $[a,b]$ and $(a,b)$. Measure theory is generally studied after topology, not before it.

Comment: sorry i am looking for a simpler explanation. i am not a maths student and lack necessary background such as continuous functions. can you explain it in a way lay person can understand? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what kind of course this is, but differences occur, for example, at the topological level. Closed intervals are compact, which is an extremely useful property to have.

For example, suppose $I$ is some interval (either open, closed, or half-open) and $f$ is a continuous function. Does $f$ achieve a maximum and minimum value on $I$? The answer is "Yes if $I$ is closed", but this might not be the case otherwise. Consider, for example, $f(x)=1/x$ on the interval $(0,1)$.

Now, on each $[c,1]$ for $c>0$, $f$ achieves a maximum value. The problem is that, as $c$ gets closer and closer to $0$, these maximum values blow up and become arbitrarily large. So, the problem stems from the fact that we can, while living in the interval, get as close as we want to $0$ without actually touching the "problem point". This is not the case for the closed interval.

This type of situation occurs very frequently in analysis. You have some object that behaves more and more erratically as you get towards the boundary of whatever set your working in. However, if the boundary is contained in the set, and you know your object behaves well on the set, we avoid the problem altogether. This last paragraph is, of course, rather hand-wavy, but hopefully it provides some intuition.